# User migration not setting custom field values correctly

Tags: 8, users, entities, migrations

I have a User migration in Drupal 8 which is coming from custom SQL tables.
The user entity in Drupal 8 has a bunch of custom fields on it (First Name, Last Name, About, etc).

When I run the migration I can go into the field data tables in Drupal 8 and see that all of the values are there in the table where they should be, meaning they migrated into the new database correctly.

If I go to the users' edit pages (/user/#/edit), the fields are completely empty.  If I then click save and wait for the page to reload, all of the migrated values magically appear in the form.

I tried running a post-migration script to manually save the users, but it still does not make the fields show up and I have to manually save the empty form for the values to show.

Here is the post-migration script I tried:

```
$ignored_users = [0, 1];
$uids = db_select('users', 'u')
  ->condition('uid', $ignored_users, 'NOT IN')
  ->fields('u', ['uid'])
  ->execute()
  ->fetchCol();

$users = user_load_multiple($uids);

foreach ($users as $user) {
  $user->save();
}
```

This is my config for the migration:

```
id: my_users
label: User Migration
migration_group: users
source:
  plugin: migrate_users
destination:
  plugin: entity:user
process:
  uid: uid
  name: name
  pass: pass
  mail: mail
  status: status
  created: created
  changed: changed
  access: access
  login: login
  langcode: language
  preferred_langcode: language
  preferred_admin_langcode: language
  init: init
  roles: roles
  user_picture:
    plugin: migration
    migration: my_files
    source: field_image_fid
  'field_about/value': body_value
  'field_about/summary': body_summary
  'field_about/format':
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: full_html
  field_first_name: field_first_name_value
  field_last_name: field_last_name_value
migration_dependencies:
  required:
    - my_files
dependencies:
  enforced:
    module:
      - my_migrate
```

Here is my user migration plugin:

```
class Users extends Nodes {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function query() {
    return $this->select('users', 'u')
      ->fields('u', array_keys($this->baseFields()))
      ->condition('uid', 0, '>');
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function fields() {
    $fields = $this->baseFields();
    $fields['field_about/format'] = $this->t('Format of body');
    $fields['field_about/value'] = $this->t('Full text of body');
    $fields['field_about/summary'] = $this->t('Summary of body');
    $fields['field_first_name'] = $this->t('First Name textfield');
    $fields['field_last_name'] = $this->t('Last Name textfield');

    return $fields;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getIds() {
    return [
      'uid' => [
        'type' => 'integer',
        'alias' => 'u',
      ],
    ];
  }

  /**
   * Returns the user base fields to be migrated.
   *
   * @return array
   *   Associative array having field name as key and description as value.
   */
  protected function baseFields() {
    return [
      'uid' => $this->t('User ID'),
      'name' => $this->t('Username'),
      'pass' => $this->t('Password'),
      'mail' => $this->t('Email address'),
      'created' => $this->t('Registered timestamp'),
      'access' => $this->t('Last access timestamp'),
      'login' => $this->t('Last login timestamp'),
      'status' => $this->t('Status'),
      'language' => $this->t('Language'),
      'picture' => $this->t('Picture'),
      'init' => $this->t('Init'),
    ];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function prepareRow(Row $row) {
    $uid = $row->getSourceProperty('uid');
    $profile_nid = $this->getProfileData($uid);

    $row->setSourceProperty(
      'body_value',
      $this->getFieldValue($profile_nid, 'field_data_body', 'body_value')
    );
    $row->setSourceProperty(
      'body_summary',
      $this->getFieldValue($profile_nid, 'field_data_body', 'body_summary')
    );

    $row->setSourceProperty(
      'field_first_name_value',
      $this->getFieldValue($profile_nid, 'field_data_field_first_name', 'field_first_name_value')
    );

    $row->setSourceProperty(
      'field_last_name_value',
      $this->getFieldValue($profile_nid, 'field_data_field_last_name', 'field_last_name_value')
    );

    return parent::prepareRow($row);
  }

  /**
   * Gets the profile data node in Drupal 7 associated with a User account.
   *
   * @param int $uid
   *   Drupal user Id.
   *
   * @return int
   *   Team Member node Id.
   */
  private function getProfileData($uid) {
    return $this->select('field_data_field_drupal_user', 'fdp')
      ->fields('fdp', ['entity_id'])
      ->condition('field_drupal_user_target_id', $uid)
      ->execute()
      ->fetchField();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the 'langocde' map in the config.  The Drupal 7 langcode did not match the Drupal 8 langcode format.

When I set a default value for langcode in the migration config the fields showed as normal.

```
  langcode:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: en
```